# Join all arrays inside a ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray generated with all the possible combinations of 3 array like this:

```
countries = ["AF"... "Zw"]
names = ["name1",... "nameN"]
var_type = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(names, var_type,countries)).T.reshape(-1, 3)
```

which gives an ndarray with the following result:

```
array([
   ['name1', 'var1', 'AF'],
   ['name1', 'var2', 'AF'],
   ['name1', 'var3', 'AF'],
   ...,
   ['nameN', 'var1', 'ZW'],
   ['nameN', 'var2', 'ZW'],
   ['nameN', 'var3', 'ZW']
])
```

And I want to join each individual sub-array to get a new array with the merged values like this:

```
array([
   "name1-var1-AF",
   "name1-var2-AF",
   "name1-var3-AF",
   ...,
   "nameN-var1-ZW",
   "nameN-var2-ZW",
   "nameN-var3-ZW"
])
```

But the only way I fond in google so far is with a for loop like this:

```
columns = []

for column in combinations:
   columns.append(str('-'.join(column)))
```

is there a more vectorized way to do this??

Comment: What is the exact dtype? Can you show exactly how the original array is constructed? I.e., an MCVE?

Comment: Edited the question with how the array is constructed, thx

Comment: Do the columns in `combinations` always have a consistent number of characters? or is it arbitrary? In the latter case, use the loop.

Comment: it might change since the names have different length

Comment: Then there is not much you can do. You can play with linear indices and mapping the locations that way, but it will be much slower than just running a python loop. Numpy works best for uniformly sized elements, and these are not.

Comment: Now if you were willing to place the variable-length string at the end, I could do it reasonably fast

Comment: You might also try something that joins a hyphen to np.char.add(np.char.add(combinations[:,0],combinations[:,1]),combinations[:,2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` does not fast compiled code for handling strings - other than the basic array manipulation that applies to any `dtype`.  Even the `np.char` functions use basic python string methods.

```
In [12]: countries = ["AF","Zw"] 
    ...: names = ["name1","name2", "nameN"] 
    ...: var_type = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'] 
    ...: combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(names, var_type,countries)).T.reshape(-1, 3)   

In [14]: ['-'.join(row) for row in _]                                                                
Out[14]: 
['name1-var1-AF',
 'name1-var2-AF',
 'name1-var3-AF',
 'name2-var1-AF',
 ...
 'nameN-var3-Zw']
```

This is basically a list operation.  Iterating on lists is faster

```
In [18]: timeit ['-'.join(row) for row in combinations]                                              
62.3 µs ± 113 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [19]: timeit ['-'.join(row) for row in combinations.tolist()]                                     
6.55 µs ± 31.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [20]: %%timeit alist = combinations.tolist() 
    ...: ['-'.join(row) for row in alist] 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                             
2.88 µs ± 3.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

And if I include the time spent creating `combinations`:

```
In [29]: %%timeit 
    ...: combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(names, var_type,countries)).T.reshape(-1, 3)    
    ...: ['-'.join(row) for row in combinations] 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                             
164 µs ± 925 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

On the other hand using `itertools.product`:

```
In [30]: timeit ['-'.join(tup) for tup in product(names, var_type, countries)]                       
4.17 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This is a case where `numpy` does not help.